# Subject being triggered not reflecting in receiving file

Tags: angular, authentication, service

I have a file (Auth.service.ts) where I am firing a subject if a POST request is successful and this fired subject is being subscribed to in a different file(header.TS). If header.TS has received this subject, a prop (authState) value in header.TS file is being updated. However, the subject is not being received and I am not sure if it is being fired at all. Plz let me know how to sort this.

Auth.service.TS:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { catchError , Subject, tap, throwError ,map } from "rxjs";
import { UserModal } from "src/app/shared/User.modal";

interface AuthSignUpResponseData{
    idToken:string ,
    email:string ,
    refreshToken:string ,
    expiresIn:string ,
    localId:string ,   
}

@Injectable()
export class authService {

    userSubject = new Subject<AuthSignUpResponseData>();
    constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
   
    signUpUser(email:string , password:string){
        return (
                this.http.post<AuthSignUpResponseData>("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyBv_CgjuTtiNaVgk8FFZTUHVhoqwG9vTso" , 
                {
                email : email , 
                password : password,
                returnSecureToken : true ,
                })
                .pipe(
                    tap(response => this.handleAuthentication())  
                    )
        )
    };

    handleAuthentication(){response => {
        let tokenExpiry = Date.now() + (+response.expiresIn)*1000;
        console.log("sent");
        let newUser = new UserModal(response.email , response.localId ,tokenExpiry , response.idToken);
        **return this.userSubject.next(newUser);**
    }
    }
}
```

The last line in the above file is firing the subject. This is caught in the header.TS file:

```
import {Component,ElementRef ,ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { authService } from "../auth/auth/Auth.service";
import { APIservice } from "../Get&Post-Service";

@Component({
    selector:"header",
    templateUrl:"header.html",
    styleUrls:['header.css']
})


export class HeaderComponent{
    title:HeaderComponent;
    subscription:Subscription;
    **authState:boolean = false;**


    constructor(private apiService:APIservice , private authService:authService){
        **this.subscription = this.authService.userSubject.subscribe(newUser => {
            this.authState == newUser;
            console.log(this.authState);**  
        })
    };
    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.authState = false;
    }
}
```

I am using the prop "authState" in  header.TS file to decide which elements of header.HTML should be displayed. I am not adding the header.HTML file as I think it is futile here. Let me know if you need the HTML file for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

Update your header.ts file as below

```
export class HeaderComponent{
    title:HeaderComponent;
    subscription:Subscription;
    **authState:boolean = false;**

    constructor(private apiService:APIservice , private authService:authService){
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.authService.userSubject.subscribe(newUser => {
            this.authState == newUser;
            console.log(this.authState);
        })
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.authState = false;
    }
}
```

The constructor is a Typescript feature used to instantiate the Typescript class.The ngOnInit function is specific to the Angular framework and is called when Angular is done creating the component

Thanks!

Comment: but when we render the component we are also creating an instance of the class right? so won't the code under constructor run then? as we are creating an instance? when the component renders for the first time an object of that class is created right? so even then the constructor code should be executed similar to ngOnInt()

Comment: on a side note, adding it in ngOnInit() did not work for the problem